# Webpack less-loader Missing Base Path on Production Build

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I've got a vue-js app that uses webpack.  Everything works fine in development and test environments, but I'm having trouble getting it to build for production.

I've got background images in the LESS files.  The image files are in `/static`.  (I'm not sure whether that's kosher or if they should be in side `src/assets`.)

At any rate, when the LESS has something like this:

```
 background-url: url("/static/img/foobar/my-image.svg")
```

Then the compilted CSS will have the same url

```
 background-url: url("/static/img/foobar/my-image.svg")
```

When the browser loaders, it can't find that imgate file. The browser is attempting to find the file here:

```
file:///static/img/foobar/my-image.svg
```

Can anyone recommend a way to prepend the absolute path when the app builds for production?

Comment: Can you please provide your Webpack configs so we can look into it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your static assets outside of our project directory in `/static` ?
Otherwise I don't get why your browser is trying to request it from `file:///static/img/foobar/my-image.svg`

anyway, your static assets should be part of your repo/project. They do not need to be in src directory, a `/static` folder within the root of your project is just fine.

when you compile your application - let's say into a *dist* folder - you should copy the images also in that dist folder. In my app I use the copy-webpack-plugin for that task (I have my images in `./public/assets/img/..` and I reference them as `/assets/img/..`)

```
    const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
    ...

    plugins: [
    ...
    /** copy all files from the public folder to the compilation root */
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
        from: 'public',
        to  : ''
    }]),
    ...
```

also you should make sure that you have the file-loader in place for your static assets. I use it like so:

```
  {
       test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\??\#?v=[.0-9]+)?$/,
       use : 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
  }
```

I hope this will help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: Yep, the `static` directory lives at the root level of the project.

I'm also using CopyWebpackPlugin. The asset files get where they need to be with no trouble.

The issue is that the URLs for background images inside the LESS aren't getting generated properly.

Comment: haven't you said that the compiled css has the same url: `background-url: url("/static/img/foobar/my-image.svg")` ?!  when that is the reference within the compiled css, than it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up moving the images into `assets/img` and then updating my webpack config to specify the directory using `publicPath`.  Here's what it ended up looking like:

```
      {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    include: [resolve('src')],
    options: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: '/[name].[hash:7].[ext]',
      publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app')
    }
```